# Is there a callback when the user accepts to share their location?

Tags: javascript, html, web

This is what I need:

When the user clicks on "share location," there will be a message like "Tracking you." If the location was found, there will be a success message like "Location found!"

I'm using the `callback` for the success case, but is there a `callback` for the tracking phase?

I'm using **HTML5** `getCurrentPosition`

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What platform are you using? What do you men by "is there a callback when the tracking phase?" Did you write one?

Comment: No, there isn't. It's up to the user's device to show them that their location is being acquired.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question a bit. I'm guessing you're talking about the HTML5 geolocation API and using the getCurrentPosition method?

Comment: Take a look at the api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be an example of it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#JavaScript_Content

I don't think there is an event for it, specifically, but you can simulate it like they do. Basically showing content like "locating you..." when you start the process and then remove that once you have the location data.

Comment: But in that case if the user doesn't share his location the "location you" text will stay there, right?

Comment: @BrunoPereira Well only if you don't change it if the location tracking fails.

Comment: Here is a quick example I threw together: https://jsfiddle.net/jgrzhsmz/. You can see that inside the click event starting on line 17 I have the status change to "locating you...". Once the location is set and it calls the success function, I remove it.

Comment: The example on that page shows "Locating..." until the process succeeds and `success` is called, or it fails and `error` is called.